# withStyles Error to apply styles for elements using classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

```
Objects are not valid as a React child 
(found: object with keys {$$typeof, render, propTypes, Naked, options, useStyles}). 
If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Code: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-dust-b1q88?file=/src/Form.js:199-1848)

```
const Form = () => {

  //Input
  const [project, setProject] = useState({
    id: "",
    name: "",
    isPublic: false
  });

  const handleChange = (prop) => (event) => {
    setProject({ ...project, [prop]: event.target.value });
  };

  const handlePermisson = (prop) => (event) => {
    setProject({ ...project, [prop]: event.target.checked });
    console.log(project);
  };
  const WithStyles = ({ classes }) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Grid container>
          <Grid item md={6}>
            <FormControl
              className="classes.bottom-gap"
              fullWidth
              value={project.id}
              onChange={handleChange("id")}
            >
              <TextField
                id="project_id"
                label="Project id"
                variant="outlined"
              />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl
              fullWidth
              value={project.name}
              onChange={handleChange("name")}
            >
              <TextField
                id="project_name"
                label="Project name"
                variant="outlined"
              />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl
              fullWidth
              value={project.id}
              onChange={handlePermisson("isPublic")}
            >
              <FormControlLabel control={<Switch />} label="Is Public" />
            </FormControl>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item md={6}></Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  };
  return withStyles(styles)(WithStyles);
};
const styles = {
  bottomgap: {
    marginBottom: "10px"
  }
};
export default Form;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to use a higher-order component (HOC) *inside* of your component.  You need to use the HOC *outside* of the component.

```
const Form = ({ classes }) => { ...
```

```
export default withStyles(styles)(Form);
```

---

You are also applying the class name as a literal string `className="classes.bottom-gap"` rather than applying the actual class name from the `classes` object.  It should be

```
className={classes.bottomgap}
```

---

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Grid,
  FormControl,
  FormControlLabel,
  Switch,
  TextField
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const Form = ({ classes }) => {
  //Input
  const [project, setProject] = useState({
    id: "",
    name: "",
    isPublic: false
  });

  const handleChange = (prop) => (event) => {
    setProject({ ...project, [prop]: event.target.value });
  };

  const handlePermisson = (prop) => (event) => {
    setProject({ ...project, [prop]: event.target.checked });
    console.log(project);
  };
    return (
      <div>
        <Grid container>
          <Grid item md={6}>
            <FormControl
              className={classes.bottomgap}
              fullWidth
              value={project.id}
              onChange={handleChange("id")}
            >
              <TextField
                id="project_id"
                label="Project id"
                variant="outlined"
              />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl
              fullWidth
              value={project.name}
              onChange={handleChange("name")}
            >
              <TextField
                id="project_name"
                label="Project name"
                variant="outlined"
              />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl
              fullWidth
              value={project.id}
              onChange={handlePermisson("isPublic")}
            >
              <FormControlLabel control={<Switch />} label="Is Public" />
            </FormControl>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item md={6}></Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
};
const styles = {
  bottomgap: {
    marginBottom: "10px"
  }
};
export default withStyles(styles)(Form);
```